# can't view react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, universal

I'm trying to create a simple application using react-native for platform independent use, I'm using Webstorm IDE on test purpose.

Now here is my project structure:

```
HelloTest:
    |---node_modules
    |---src
    |     |---index.js
    |---package.json
    |package_lock.json
```

Now here is my `index.js` :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text>Hello, world!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And her is my `package.json` :

```
{
  "name": "HelloTest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node_module": "^0.0.0",
    "react-native": "^0.61.3"
  }
}
```

And I'm using **start**, the application starts running at *`port:8081`*

I go to that address, and what I get is this :

[image: react-native-no-preview]

**I'm not getting any preview, what should I do, do I need to change any configuration? **

The command webstorm used is this :

`E:\node\node.exe E:\node\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js --package react-native-cli react-native init HelloTest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a "preview" you need to run the app as follow:

- iOS: `npx react-native run-ios`
- Android: `npx react-native run-android`

Answer (score 1):

you should create your react native project using command `npx react-native init AwesomeProject` according to [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started). there are many pre-configurations for react native and also you are missing few packages. please fallow react native documentation.

Comment: everything was fine except, I was typing `react-native run-android`, instead of `npx react-native run-android`

Comment: yap. they have changed some things around commands and i was also confused when i started react native after few months with old commands.